# cannot calculate and output displayed at netbeans instead of window panel

Tags: java, swing

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package pbl2;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Main
{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame f = new JFrame("WELCOME TO ULEQ MAYANG CAFE");
         f.setSize(1200, 500);
         f.setLocation(0, 0);
         f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter( ){

         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){System.exit(0);}

      });

      JPanel entreePanel = new JPanel();
      final ButtonGroup entreeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      JRadioButton radioButton;
      System.out.print("Please Select Your Food : \n\n");

      entreePanel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Uleq Fried Chicken(2 Pieces) = RM6.00"));
      radioButton.setActionCommand("Uleq Fried Chicken(2 Pieces) = RM6.00");
      entreeGroup.add(radioButton);
      entreePanel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Uleq Fried Chicken(5Pieces) = RM15.00"));
      radioButton.setActionCommand("Uleq Fried Chicken(5Pieces) = RM15.00");
      entreeGroup.add(radioButton);
      entreePanel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Panera Bread = RM3.00"));
      radioButton.setActionCommand("Panera Bread = RM3.00");
      entreeGroup.add(radioButton);
      entreePanel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Hoka Hoka Bento = RM4.50"));
      radioButton.setActionCommand("Hoka Hoka Bento = RM4.50");
      entreePanel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Special Uleq Burger = RM6.00"));
      radioButton.setActionCommand("Special Uleq Burger = RM6.00");
      entreeGroup.add(radioButton);

      final JPanel condimentsPanel = new JPanel();
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Orange Pulpy = RM3.80"));
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Coca Cola = RM2.50"));
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Pepsi = RM2.50"));
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Mineral Water = RM1.00"));
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Special Uleq Latte = RM3.50"));
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Ribena = RM2.00"));
      condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Mango Juice = RM3.00"));

      JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel( );
         JButton orderButton = new JButton("THANK YOU FOR PURCHASING AT ULEQ MAYANG CAFE,PLEASE CLICK AND WE WILL PROCEED YOUR ORDER");
           orderPanel.add(orderButton);

    Container content = f.getContentPane( );
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    content.add(entreePanel);

    content.add(condimentsPanel);
    content.add(orderPanel);


    orderButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String entree =
    entreeGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand( );
    System.out.println(entree + " ");
    Component[] components = condimentsPanel.getComponents( );
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox)components[i];
    if (cb.isSelected( ))
    System.out.println("Drinks order:" + cb.getText( ));
}
}
});

f.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

//** help me!!!!*//
i wanna calculate the price but i dont know.. im stupid about java.. and the "food order" and "drink order" is not displayed at the window but at the output at the net bean.. sorry for my broken english.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What confuses you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to break your problem down.

You have a number of items which can be added to an order.  At some time, you need to calculate the total of that order.

A item has a description and price.

A order may contain 0 or more items.

Basically, you need some way to model these elements.  When a UI element representing the item is clicked, you need to either add or remove it from your order.

When the user clicks the button, you need to ask the order to calculate the total.

This is the basic concept of the model, view, control paradigm.

Instead of dumping a bunch of controls onto a window, you need to model these distinct elements in some way and produce a UI that represents it.

Let's start with the model...

```
// The order, which holds a series of items...
// You should be able to see getTally method :D
public class Order {

    private List<Item> items;

    public Order() {
        items = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void add(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public void remove(Item item) {
        items.remove(item);
    }

    public double getTally() {

        double tally = 0;
        for (Item item : items) {
            tally += item.getPrice();
        }

        return tally;

    }

}

// A basic item, which has a description and a price...
public class Item {

    private String text;
    private double price;

    public Item(String text, double price) {
        this.text = text;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}
```

Next, we need some way to model this to the screen...Now, because there is so much repeated code, I would create a series of method to make your life easier...

```
// Formats the item for the display...
protected String toString(Item item) {
    return item.getText() + " (" + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(item.getPrice()) + ")";
}

// Creates a radio button for the specified Item...
protected JRadioButton createRadioButton(ButtonGroup group, Item item) {
    JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton(toString(item));
    rb.addItemListener(new ItemHandler(order, item));
    group.add(rb);
    return rb;
}
```

Now, you simple add this to your UI as simple as...

```
entreePane.add(createRadioButton(bg, new Item("Uleq Fried Chicken(2 Pieces)", 6.0)));
```

Now, we need some way to know when to add or remove an item from our `Order`.  Thankfully, this can be taken care by using a `ItemListener`, which will let us know when a button has being selected or deselected...

```
public class ItemHandler implements ItemListener {

    private Order order;
    private Item item;

    public ItemHandler(Order order, Item item) {
        this.order = order;
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).isSelected()) {
            order.add(item);
        } else {
            order.remove(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when you need the tally, you can just ask the `Order` for it...

Take a closer look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an item listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for more details...

Note: I've not included the creation of check boxes, but the basic process is the same as creating the radio buttons, just without the button group ;)

It should also be noted, that a `JComboBox`, `JList` and/or `JTable` could be used to provide the same functionality...